# read file: OS Error: No such file or directory

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]I want to use the following code for encryption and decryption rsa

```
Future<void> main () async {
  
  final publicKey = await parseKeyFromFile<RSAPublicKey>('assets/res/pubkey.pem');
  final privKey = await parseKeyFromFile<RSAPrivateKey>('assets/res/privkey.pem');

  final plainText = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit';
  final encrypter = Encrypter(RSA(publicKey: publicKey, privateKey: privKey));

  final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText);
  final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted);

  print(decrypted); 
  print(encrypted.base64);
```

I generated PEM files with Open SSL But after placement and run
I have the following error:

> E/flutter ( 9633): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/res/pubkey.pem' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Is there a way to fix this?
Because everything I did is useless

Otherwise can I enter the key directly into the code?
For example in the following code snippet?
Or put the key in a string variable and put it in the following code?

```
  final publicKey = await parseKeyFromFile<RSAPublicKey>(string variable);\\ use here??
  final privKey = await parseKeyFromFile<RSAPrivateKey>(string variable); \\use here??
```

[image]

Comment: the error message `No such file or directory,`seems to be pretty clear and not really related to encryption. But from here we can't see if the filename and path are correct or if you have access rights to this file or path and so on.

Comment: Hi, I uploaded the images if it helps @jps

Comment: You open a file with a relative path. That means from the directory in which your program is executed you have to reach 'assetts/...'. I changed the headline to your real problem.